# What is the safest way to store progress flags in a "fool-proof" program?

Tags: c#, flags

I have been tasked to create a program that launches upon start-up and waits for a trigger to begin it's process. I have a need to track the state of the progress in an as safe as possible way. The definition of safe being; "will never miss to pack or send."

There are numerous failures the program has to endure.

- Power failure during a process.
- Network failure before or during a packing/moving process.
- Other disturbances in the processes.

My idea is to use a simple "flag" system, written to a `.txt` file. Upon start-up, the program will read the file and check where in the line of getting-packing-sending it was when it was disturbed. The step that was started but not finished will then be retried and then it will resume.

The question I have is based on the risk that it is disturbed during the writing of these flags, and some possible way to minimize the risk of this happening. Maybe by using a different "flag"-format, writing methods, etc?

**EDIT:** Simplicity is an important factor since this operation will preform in a case of emergency.
**EDIT2:** Self-contained answers are preferred since the specs state that the program is to be "light-weight", and the target system is already bogged down with excessive HDD and memory use.

Comment: Perhaps you can write the progress into a database and wrap each step in an [ACID transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic : While it's certainly a clever way to approach the problem and to assure total security. I would rather implement something more self contained in the app, to minimize the footprint on the target system.

Comment: use a ups and redundant hardware.

Comment: And remember that if you want to produce code that safeguards against sudden powerloss, you need to make sure the cache buffers are synced.

Comment: Then why not use some embedded database, such as SQLite or MS SQL Server Compact?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic The system already uses a MS SQL server, for what I am not sure since I am rather new to this project. Could I not just create myself a table on the existing database and use that?

Comment: @MarcusWigert Sure. You can even use the security features already built into SQL Server to ensure only your application can access such table.

Comment: How about this workflow to write new data to your file(s): Write to a "temp.txt" file. If it's finished, delete "current.txt" then rename "temp.txt" to "current.txt". When your program starts up there are multiple possibilities: temp.txt exists and current.txt exists -> temp.txt might be corr

Comment: @Traubenfuchs I think your way might be more cumbersome than to just use one file and restart the process if the flag is nothing but `true`. Minimizing the time writing to the `.txt` minimizes the risk of it being interrupted.

Comment: @MarcusWigert Be very careful if you decide to use simple file(s) - as Lasse V. Karlsen pointed out, just because you wrote something to a file, does not mean it actually reached non-volatile storage (and safety against power loss). IMHO, it will be simpler (and more likely to achieve correct behavior) for you to just reuse the work that had already gone into making databases [durable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(database_systems)).